# Compute $\int_C xe^y\;dx+x^2y\;dy,\; y=3,\ 0\le x \le 2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Compute $\int_C xe^y\;dx+x^2y\;dy,\; y=3,\ 0\le x \le 2$

In most of the problems I've done just far they have defined points which helped me to build a position vector.  How do I get started with this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll just use the usual approach.  Parametrize the path over which you're integrating.  Here's an easy parametrization: $(x,y) = (t,3),\ t\in [0,2]$.  Then just plug in:  $$\int_C xe^y\;dx+x^2y\;dy = \int_0^2 (t)e^{(3)}\ d(t)+(t)^2(3)\ d(3) = \int_0^2 te^3\ dt + 3t^2\cdot 0\ dt = e^3\int_0^2 t\ dt$$

Comment: Thanks for this solution!  How did you come up with this parametrization?

Comment: This exercise sets $y=3$ so we definitely have $(x,y) = (\cdot, 3)$.  So then I just set $x=t$ where $0\le t\le 2$ so that I could constrain $x$ as needed (and because it's considered inelegant to reuse the same variable name when parametrizing your curve/ surface/ etc).

Comment: So clear and concise!  Thank you

Comment: In the last step, wouldn't it be $e^3\int^2_0 3t\; dt$?  In the previous step $3t^2$ is being multiplied by $0$ so I'm not sure where the $3t$ came from...

Comment: Sorry.  There was an extraneous $3$.  Now it's fixed.